# Use method="post" with a nested form in angular formly

Tags: angularjs, forms, angular-formly

How would one use the `method="post"` with nested forms like are found in this example: http://jsbin.com/gohefojiqa/1/edit?html,js,output ?

I'm guessing it has something to do with this: https://scotch.io/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-the-angularjs-way but I'm not sure how to implement it in a multistep/nested form like are present in the angular-wizard form.

Comment: Hi Tyler, the fact that you included references to some tutorials is clear indication that you have done some basic research - good. However I think you need to give it your best attempt, and if you encounter errors/issues - then you can post a more direct question.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I'll keep that in mind the next time I run into a problem. I actually just figured it out though.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my HTML was messed up...

Also, an alert in the example was also throwing it off a bit too. Fixed those two things and now we're good.

Comment: Great stuff, please accept your own answer so that you question is marked as answered and won't appear on the questions queue. Happy coding!

Comment: Will do, it looks like I can't accept my own comment until tomorrow though for some reason I can't do that until tomorrow: https://www.evernote.com/l/AMFZtqQ3QThDzLOq6YCoIE7N8ou5VtkiXYQB/image.png